# Failed to apply plugin class 'nebula.plugin.release.ReleasePlugin'

Tags: gradle, micrometer, netflix-nebula-plugins

Trying to build micrometer version 1.5.9.

Getting following error:-

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/abc/Desktop/micrometer/build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'micrometer'.

> Failed to apply plugin class 'nebula.plugin.release.ReleasePlugin'.
> /Users/abc/Desktop/micrometer/config (Is a directory)

build.gradle

Line# 29 apply plugin: 'io.spring.release'

classpath 'io.spring.gradle:spring-release-plugin:0.20.1'
classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-project-plugin:3.4.0'

Any lead, what exactly is wrong here?

Thanks